# How to add extra price on configurable product and it's child (Simple Product) magento 2x

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-product, price, simple-product, configurable-price

[image]**How to add extra price on configurable product and it's child (Simple Product) magento 2x**

like this : ($1.95 for configurable and $1.25 for it's child)

I want to add this price on frontend. After adding extra price, checkout and cart functionality use this new price ***i.e* newPrice = productPrice + extraPrice;**

Comment: For this you need to used magento event observer to set new price.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, Is there any method like [this method](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-product-price-change-with-plugin/) ?  I have tried this one but this override the price same for all products. on product list page.

Comment: Maybe this can help?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173979/how-to-change-the-product-price-with-a-plugin-in-magento-2-1