# Magento 2 override associated product price (configurable and it's child)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, zend-framework, configurable-price

I have all configurable products on my website and **I want to add the extra charges** (after some calculation and conditions) to product price **by overriding method** or anything else which follow the Magento standard.

> I have follow the following scenario:
>
> I have tried this by using plugin method. It override the configurable product price only not it's child. Also not working properly on product list page.

**1.etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="product_price_change"
            type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\Updateprice"
            sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**2.Plugin/Updateprice.php**

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin;

class Updateprice
{
    /**
     *  \Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data $helper
     *
     * @var Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_helper;

    protected $_configurable;

    protected $product;

    public function __construct(
        \Namespace\Modulename\Helper\Data $helper,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_configurable = $configurable;
        $this->_product = $product;
    }

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result) {
        if($subject->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
            return $result + $this->_helper->getAdditionalPrice($subject);
        }else{
            return $result + $this->_helper->chkAdditionalPrice($subject);
        }
    }
}
```

**getAdditionalPrice** function is defined in helper which have some calculation and return additional price according to product attribute otherwise it returns false;

I have also tried **catalog_product_get_final_price** magento event. This is working fine for "Simple Product" not for the associated simple product (configurable simple product).

> I want to carry configurable product price to cart and checkout.
>
> Any suggestion would be appreciated.
>
> Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173979/how-to-change-the-product-price-with-a-plugin-in-magento-2-1 maybe this helps